# Windows 7 stuck on loading screen

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox

I am installing Windows 7 using UEFI in Virtualbox and it is stuck on the "Starting Windows" screen. When I used legacy bios, it works normally. What is happening and how do I get it to work?

[image]

Comment: Does Windows 7 support UEFI?

Comment: Windows 7 64 bit supports UEFI.